# validating my ckeditor text area with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have a text area which I've used ckeditor on:

```
<form name="product_edit" action="products.php" method="post" id="edit_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea name="products_description" wrap="soft" cols="75%" rows="20" id="products_description"></textarea>
```

Also after including jQuery I have the following to validate the form:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#edit_form').submit(function() {
     if ($('#products_description').val() == '') {
        alert('Please include a product description.');
        return false;
     }
  }); // end submit()
}); // end ready()
```

I also have a couple of other fields I validate which aren't included for brevity.

My problem is that while all the other fields work fine with that, the text area sometimes doesn't. If I type stuff in it sometimes doesn't recognize it and still pops up the alert. Then if I go back and click (I don't even have to type anything more) and try to submit it works.

Any guesses as to why?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/DoomHamster/Gteqc/

Comment: @BradleyMountford Yeah the fiddle seems to work, but does it use ckeditor?

Comment: @Raminson hi there, I'll edit my question to include the view->source of the page

Comment: OK looks like its really hard to post lots of code on this site. Can you really not copy and paste nicely indented code without having to re-indent everything!?! WTF you can see the source here: http://belfastswimmingteacher.com/new_2.txt

Answer (score 0):

Is this still an issue? If not, post your solution.

CKEeditor does not work like that, you don't get data like `$('#products_description').val()`. CKEditor doesn't use the textarea directly, it generates an iframe to use instead of it. To get the value, call `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData()` where editor1 in your case might be `products_description`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me while no description is added works fine but if you put some space it is considered as content.Please add required attribute for your textarea.
 **Please include jquery validator and jquery library.**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#edit_form').validate({
        ignore: [],         
        rules: {
                    products_description: {
                            required: function() 
                            {
                                    CKEDITOR.instances.products_description.updateElement();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {             
                    products_description: "مطلوب"
                    },
                    /* use below section if required to place the error*/
                    errorPlacement: function(error, element) 
                    {
                        if (element.attr("name") == "products_description") 
                       {
                        error.insertAfter("#cke_description");
                        } else {
                        error.insertAfter(element);
                        }
                    }
                });
    });
```